# Node.js: res.redirect function is not working

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, express, response.redirect

***res.redirect  function is used to redirect the user to another page by clicking a button.  But the function's not working. Please find the code below.***

```
    const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const https = require("https");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));


app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});

app.post("/failure", function (req, res) {
    res.redirect("/");
});

app.post("/success", function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/");
});



app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    console.log("The server is running at port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Consider adding your client-side code as well so that people could discern what problems you could have. Also, what do you mean by _not working_?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `app.post` to `app.get`:

```js
app.get("/success", function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
});
```

below your other routes and try calling again